# Забаглся ROOM в телефоне

Tags: android, room

Я кое-что поменял в структуре класса. Рум, конечно же, начал ругаться что "существующая структура БД не совпадает с новой".
Приложение с телефона удалил. Перезагружал. Чистил кэш проекта. Пересобирал Gradle.
Все бестолку.
На эмуляторе все работает отлично. Достаточно просто удалить приложение и все работает хорошо.
А вот на реальном телефоне не помогает.
Samsung Galaxy A12
Что еще нужно сделать, чтобы полностью снести приложение с телефона?

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: @Andrew я не знаю что еще добавить =( похоже, что файл БД не удалился из самого телефона при удалении приложения. проблема исключительно на одном устройстве.

Comment: может мусор остался после удаления приложения, попробуйте штатными чистильщиками почистить, может что-то пофиксит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше устройство как минимум на андроид 9, так что вы всегда можете найти файлы БД с помощью `Device File Explorer` в debug режиме. Вкладка с этим инструментом находится на правом углу студии. Проследуйте по пути `data/data/имя_приложения/databases/`

Убедитесь, что файлы удаляются. Чтобы удалить кеш на вашем устройстве: `пальцем вверх / вниз> Настройки > Приложения . Выберите приложение, выберите « Хранилище» > « Очистить кеш» и « Очистить данные» .`

В новой версии room доступны автомиграции, которые исключают подобные проблемы

> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#automated

Так же попробуйте добавить fallbackToDestructiveMigration

```
val builder = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "database.db")
builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
```

fallbackToDestructiveMigration сработает если повысить версию базы, относительно предыдущей.

Comment: большое спасибо! через АС залез в папку приложения и там и правда была старая БД!